# How to connect multiple gateways to become one whole network?

Tags: networking

I'm currently living in a friend's place that has the following strange network configuration:

- Modem at 192.168.1.1 connected to DSL with DHCP server ON (henceforth referred to as "Modem")
- Buffalo DD WRT at 192.168.11.1 physically connected to Modem via WAN port,
  set as GATEWAY with DHCP Server ON
  (henceforth referred to as "Gateway 1")
- Buffalo DD WRT at 192.168.11.2 physically connected to Modem via WAN port, set as GATEWAY with DHCP Server ON (henceforth referred to as "Gateway 2")
- Each unit has WiFi on with its own SSID

I won't go too much into why each Buffalo is set as a Gateway, but for the current situation let's say that I cannot change the port and Gateway settings into proper AP settings.

With this configuration it looks like each Gateway is its own isolated network. When I am connected to Gateway 1 I cannot see devices in Gateway 2, and vice versa.

I would like all devices to be able to see each other within this configuration regardless of which Gateway it is connected to. How can I do this without having to purchase new equipment or spend money?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You might try this tool.  Not sure if it can help with multiple Gateways though.  At least it is Free to try:  http://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware